# Token decoding error Illegal base64 character 22

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt

I have a Spring 2.7.10 project with java 11 and java-jwt 4.3 and for some strange reason it generates the token but when I make the get request with it it gives a validation error, but I don't see any error in the code. I leave you the configuration and the token: This is the token that generates

```json
"jwttoken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ1c3VhcmlvIjp7Im5vbWJyZSI6IkFkbWluIiwibGljZW5jaWEiOiJtMSJ9LCJleHAiOjE2ODAxODE0NzUsImlhdCI6MTY4MDA3MzQ3NX0.rbEM5oOeiucst0bAa0PKHEkAao7zAAUmCd_A3bualFWo83xXTSstAQIhHDLpf0F9LFPEBDF2mzlCI7w_6b2LEg"
```

This is the one that happened to the request that you see that it is the same:

```
"Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ1c3VhcmlvIjp7Im5vbWJyZSI6IkFkbWluIiwibGljZW5jaWEiOiJtMSJ9LCJleHAiOjE2ODAxODE0NzUsImlhdCI6MTY4MDA3MzQ3NX0.rbEM5oOeiucst0bAa0PKHEkAao7zAAUmCd_A3bualFWo83xXTSstAQIhHDLpf0F9LFPEBDF2mzlCI7w_6b2LEg"
```

The token class that fails on the line

```java
DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
```

This is the class

```java
@Component
public class JwtToken {

    private final String secret;

    public JwtToken(@Value("${jwt.secret}") String secret) {
        this.secret = secret;
    }

    public String obtenerIdentificadorDelToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, DecodedJWT::getSubject);
    }

    public Instant obtenerVencimientoDelToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, DecodedJWT::getExpiresAt).toInstant();
    }

    public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<DecodedJWT, T> claimsResolver) {
        final DecodedJWT decodedJWT = decodeToken(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(decodedJWT);
    }

    private DecodedJWT decodeToken(String token) {
        try {
            JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC512(secret)).build();
            DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
            return jwt;
        } catch (JWTDecodeException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error decodificando el token", exception);
        }
    }

    private Boolean haExpiradoElToken(String token) {
        final Instant expiration = obtenerVencimientoDelToken(token);
        return expiration.isBefore(Instant.now());
    }

    public boolean esMedico(String token) {
        final DecodedJWT decodedJWT = decodeToken(token);
        final Map<String, Object> userMap = decodedJWT.getClaim("usuario").asMap();
        return userMap.get("licencia") != null;
    }

    public String generarToken(Logable user) {
        final Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        final Map<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
        Medico medico = null;
        Paciente paciente = null;
        if (user instanceof Medico) {
            userMap.put("licencia", user.getIdentifier());
            medico = (Medico) user;
            userMap.put("nombre", medico.getNombre());
        } else if (user instanceof Paciente) {
            userMap.put("nss", user.getIdentifier());
            paciente = (Paciente) user;
            userMap.put("nombre", paciente.getNombre());
        }
        claims.put("usuario", new HashMap<>(userMap));
        return doGenerateToken(claims);
    }

    private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims) {
        final Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC512(secret);
        final Date now = Date.from(Instant.now());
        final Date expirationTime = Date.from(Instant.now().plusSeconds(30 * 60 * 60));
        Map<String, Object> usuarioClaims = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Object> originalUsuarioClaims = (Map<String, Object>) claims.get("usuario");
        usuarioClaims.putAll(originalUsuarioClaims);
        return JWT.create().withIssuedAt(now).withExpiresAt(expirationTime).withClaim("usuario", usuarioClaims)
                .sign(algorithm);
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, String expectedSubject) {
        try {
            final String identifier = obtenerIdentificadorDelToken(token);
            return (identifier.equals(expectedSubject) && !haExpiradoElToken(token));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error al validar el token JWT", e);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class of filter

```java
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private ServiciosJwtUsuarios jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private final JwtToken jwtTokenUtil;

    public JwtRequestFilter(JwtToken jwtTokenUtil) {
        this.jwtTokenUtil = jwtTokenUtil;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String identifier = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                identifier = jwtTokenUtil.obtenerIdentificadorDelToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (JWTDecodeException exception) {
                logger.error("No se pudo obtener el token JWT o el token JWT ha expirado", exception);
            }
        }
        if (identifier != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(identifier);
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, identifier)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

The error on the console:

> Caused by: com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTDecodeException: The input is
> not a valid base 64 encoded string. Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 22
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error decodificando el token

complete log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error decodificando el token
    at com.proyecto.config.JwtToken.decodeToken(JwtToken.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.proyecto.config.JwtToken.getClaimFromToken(JwtToken.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.proyecto.config.JwtToken.obtenerIdentificadorDelToken(JwtToken.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.proyecto.config.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTDecodeException: The input is not a valid base 64 encoded string.
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTDecoder.<init>(JWTDecoder.java:46) ~[java-jwt-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier.verify(JWTVerifier.java:444) ~[java-jwt-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
    at com.proyecto.config.JwtToken.decodeToken(JwtToken.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 22
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:848) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:589) ~[na:na]
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTDecoder.<init>(JWTDecoder.java:41) ~[java-jwt-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Exactly what are you offering as the token? Assuming the error uses hexadecimal numbers, then character 22 is `"`, which means it attempted to decode something enclosed in double quotes as base64, while a double quote is not a valid base64 character. Also, please post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: I have posted the TOKEN that the login`s petition have given to me. If the TOKEN is the problem, maybe that the reason why is not working. But I don´t know what is happening

Comment: As an aside: You do not need to convert your `Instant` to an old-fashioned `Date`. The builder has [`withIssuedAt(Instant)`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.auth0/java-jwt/4.3.0/com/auth0/jwt/JWTCreator.Builder.html#withIssuedAt(java.time.Instant)) and `withExpiresAt(Instant)` methods. And compared to `Instant.now().plusSeconds(30 * 60 * 60)` would it be easier to read `Instant.now().plus(30, ChronoUnit.HOURS)` or even `Instant.now().plus(Duration.ofDays(1).plusHours(6))`?

Comment: like?  private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims) {
  final Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC512(secret);
  final Instant now = Instant.now();
  final Instant expirationTime = Instant.now().plus(Duration.ofDays(1));
  Map<String, Object> usuarioClaims = new HashMap<>();
  Map<String, Object> originalUsuarioClaims = (Map<String, Object>) claims.get("usuario");
  usuarioClaims.putAll(originalUsuarioClaims);
  return JWT.create().withIssuedAt(now).withExpiresAt(expirationTime).withClaim("usuario", usuarioClaims)
    .sign(algorithm);
 }

Comment: Looks a lot better to me. In addition I would probably just read the clock once and set the expiration using `final Instant expirationTime = now.plus(Duration.ofDays(1));`.